# How to store Basketball player positions in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, multidimensional-array

I'd like to store basketball player positions in ruby.

For Example: Center (c), Point Guard (pg)... and even Trainer (trainer) and Co-Trainer (co_trainer).

Currently I have:

```
  POSITIONS = [
    ["trainer", "Trainer"],
    ["co_trainer", "Co-Trainer"],
    ["sg", "Shooting Guard"],
    ["sf", "Small Forward"],
    ["pg", "Point Guard"],
    ["pf", "Power Forward"],
    ["c", "Center"]
  ]
```

It would be nice to be able to search through the positions by fullname "Trainer" or shortcut "trainer" or an ID.

With my multidimensional array this is not possible. :S

Hope somebody has a hint for me!

Comment: Sounds like you want a [hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html).

Comment: Why is it you think it's not possible to search a multidimensional array?

Comment: @meagar I'm a newbie and i didn't find a way to do this :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a hash?

```
POSITIONS = { :trainer => "Trainer",
              :co_trainer => "Co-Trainer",
              :sg => "Shooting Guard",
              :pg => "Point Guard",
              :sf => "Small Forward",
              :pf => "Power Forward",
              :c => "Center" }
```

Then you could use some of Ruby's functions for hash... Might get you closer to what you're looking for.

Generally hashes are without order, but if you need the index of a position, say the string `"pg"`, you could do:

```
1.9.3p448 :016 > POSITIONS.keys.map(&:to_s).index("pg")
 => 3
```

... or to save yourself from mapping `to_s`, you could do:

```
1.9.3p448 :017 > POSITIONS.keys.index("pg".to_sym)
 => 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Let's say I have the the string `pg` and want the index in the hash of it. How would I do this?

Comment: Generally hashes aren't ordered, but you could "order" it based on how items are added to the hash.  But I'll update the answer with how you can do this.